# How to make the footer not take up half of the page?

Tags: reactjs, svg, tailwind-css, footer

So I have this svg as the footer and when I check in the developer tools it shows that it is taking up half of the page. I want the svg to only contain in the expected space without taking up extra space in the page since other elements cannot be positioned due to this issue.

```
    <footer className='absolute bottom-0 w-full'>
      <svg
        className='fill-green'
        viewBox='0 0 500 150'
        preserveAspectRatio='none'
        xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
      >
        <defs>
          <filter id='shadow'>
            <feDropShadow
              dx='0'
              dy='0'
              stdDeviation='2'
              flood-color='#159F68'
            />
          </filter>

          <path
            id='footer-shadow'
            className='stroke-none'
            d='M29.86,179.11 C100.86,200.36 200.94,60.48 450.84,180.09 L363.96,855.44 L0.00,190.00 Z'
          ></path>
        </defs>
        <g>
          <use href='#footer-shadow' filter='url(#shadow)'></use>
          <text
            className='fill-modern-green text-sm'
            x='52%'
            y='95%'
            dominant-baseline='middle'
            text-anchor='middle'
          >
            All rights reserved.
          </text>
        </g>
      </svg>
    </footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define width and height through the styles attribute for footer and svg. For example:

```
    {/* Height of footer is 30px */}
    <footer className='absolute bottom-0 w-full' style={{width: '100%', height: '30px'}}>

      {/* SVG Height based on the footer height */}
      <svg
        style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}
        className='fill-green'
        viewBox='0 0 500 150'
        preserveAspectRatio='none'
        xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
      >
        <defs>
          <filter id='shadow'>
            <feDropShadow
              dx='0'
              dy='0'
              stdDeviation='2'
              flood-color='#159F68'
            />
          </filter>

          <path
            id='footer-shadow'
            className='stroke-none'
            d='M29.86,179.11 C100.86,200.36 200.94,60.48 450.84,180.09 L363.96,855.44 L0.00,190.00 Z'
          ></path>
        </defs>
        <g>
          <use href='#footer-shadow' filter='url(#shadow)'></use>
          <text
            className='fill-modern-green text-sm'
            x='52%'
            y='95%'
            dominant-baseline='middle'
            text-anchor='middle'
          >
            All rights reserved.
          </text>
        </g>
      </svg>
    </footer>
```

Comment: Still the svg is taking up half of the page.

Comment: Look at the example https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-tree-s7qgew?file=/src/App.js

Comment: The shape of the svg is getting destroyed in that case.